# how do it Configure user level security whether only registered customers order the product.?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

i have develop localhost website but i have not Configure user level security whether only registered customers can make an order on product for in my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a core functionality but pretty easy to do.
In `catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` wrap the add to cart button in an `if` statement that checks if the user is logged in

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will prevent guest users from creating a cart and ordering the products